# Gridview: Display row one by one on a page

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have some 200 records to be displayed in a grid view on a homepage. It takes about 5 minutes to process the records before the grid view is completely displayed on the page.

How do I modify this so that the rows are displayed on the page one by one till all the records are displayed.

```
Process record 1 -> display on the page
Process record 2 -> display on the page
Process record 3 -> display on the page
.
.
.
Process record n -> display on the page
```

At last grid view will be displayed with all the records.

Comment: I don't know about ASP but usually there's a way to manually `flush` the output during your processing and send the available HTML code to the client.

Comment: the best practice is to use pagination, and display 10-20 rows at the time, if you want to display all rows you can handle the scroll event via ajax and load next 10-20 rows, and so on .. till 200 rows

Comment: If it takes 5 minutes you should investigate many things. 200 is not a big number neither for reading from DB and processing nor for being displayed. Anyway, after fixing this issue, you can use pagination along with some scrolling events.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax to load data on page scroll. When the user scroll down, the page will send a request to the server to fetch the data and display it. This will improve your page in many ways and this will be useful even if you have a lot of rows to display.

Here [Mudassar Khan at www.aspsnippets.com/](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Load-on-demand-data-in-GridView-on-scroll-using-ASPNet-and-jQuery-AJAX.aspx) has given the complete demo about the same trick.

I hope, this will surely help you.